# delete records in one table based on criteria in a different table

Tags: ms-access

I want to delete records in one table based on criteria in a different table , but I am getting the error message :"specify the table containing records you want to delete" (I only want to delete all of the records in table "RO", table "CO" is only for criteria purposes). Please provide me with the proper SQL to copy and paste (I dont know SQL. I use the query builder).

```
DELETE CO.ID, CO.PRINTED_DATE, RO.STATUS, RO.orderID, RO.CREATE_DATE, RO.NAME, RO.cust_ID, RO.lines, RO.PICKER, RO.COMMENTS, RO.sls_rep, RO.weight, RO.PO_number, RO.Tracking_Number, RO.ship_via, RO.nmbrOfBoxes
FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS RO 
LEFT JOIN SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS CO ON RO.orderID = CO.ID
WHERE (((RO.STATUS)="C" Or (RO.STATUS)="X")) OR (((CO.ID) Is Null)) OR (((CO.PRINTED_DATE) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax for a delete query that has conditions from another table:

```
DELETE tmpReleasedOrders.*
FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS RO 
     LEFT JOIN SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS CO ON (RO.orderID = CO.ID)
WHERE (RO.STATUS="C") OR (RO.STATUS="X") OR (CO.ID Is Null)
```

Comment: I get an error: "The Microsoft Jet database engine does not recognize 'tmpReleasedOrders.*' as a valid field name or expression." The fix seems to be to alter `DELETE tmpReleasedOrders.* FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS RO...` to `DELETE RO.*
FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS RO...`

Comment: "You don't need to specify field names in a delete" -- I'm not sure it makes much sense to use `*` as a placeholder for a column list either, or specifying a table correlation name (rather than the table itself) come to that. I prefer this: `DELETE FROM tmpReleasedOrders WHERE STATUS IN ('C', 'X') OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS CO WHERE CO.ID = tmpReleasedOrders.orderID);`

Comment: I am having the same problem and have tried to correct the syntax based on JohnFx's suggestion. Here is my code. Is there a problem being caused by the spaces in the table name? The Registered Users table is linked to a Sharepoint site. `DELETE [Registered Users].* FROM [Registered Users]
INNER JOIN RegisteredUsersInventory ON ([Registered Users].ModUseID = RegisteredUsersInventory.ModUseID) WHERE (RegisteredUsersInventory.ModUse_EndDT Is Not Null);`